# url shortener with IP tracking

Tags: tracking, url-shortening

Is there any url shortener with IP tracking? I have tried bit.ly but it only tracks ip country. Any other redirect service with IP tracking?

Comment: Questions about web sites and services are now considered off topic.

Comment: I -highly- doubt this exists, it would be an awful security risk. You could, however, write your own, which stackoverflow.com would be more than happy to help you with :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature listing at this [URL Shortners Knol](http://knol.google.com/k/url-shorteners)

One of them is [BudUrl](http://budurl.com/),

> BudURL is more than just a url shrinking tool – a lot more. Once a url has been turned into a BudURL, you can track click information that will reveal a tremendous amount of information about the click activity of each link.

<sup>I've not checked how good it is though. Here is [a sample from their features page](http://budurl.com/page/features).</sup>

[image]